# Shopware 6 calculate Promotion discounts on products

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Im programming a Shopware 6 plugin right now to track prices of products including promotions. Is there a method or function to retrieve all products with their new prices that match a specific promotion discount? Or what is the best way to calculate the price of a product after a discount has been applied?

I've already looked in the documentation but haven't really figured it out. It seems that I definitely need the shopping cart for this. I've also tried a few things to create a shopping cart in my plugin and then add products and the discount there. Unfortunately, that didn't work. In the end, I only managed to retrieve the prices by submitting a "fake-order" with my discount code and then reading the discount from the order_line_item database table.